# Запуск файла, а затем его закрытие

Tags: python, ос

Мне нужно, чтобы запустился аудиофайл и через некоторое время закрылся. Запускал через os.startfile, но через него нельзя сделать закрытие. Есть ли какая-нибудь альтернатива?

Comment: Я  так понимаю, что нельзя узнать какое приложение будет запущено. Тогда..запустить, с помощью psutil перебрать процессы и найти процесс, где в proc,cmdline() наш файл, послать процессу `terminate()` (и чуть погодя, если нужно, `kill`)

Comment: Обычно музыка запускается через проигрыватель windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смотрим через какую программу запускается аудиофайл. Например через `Groove Music`.

Далее открываем Диспетчер задач --> Детали.

Открываем `Groove Music`, смотрим что добавилось в колонке Имя.

У меня добавляется: `Music.UI`.

Теперь мы знаем как называется файл играющий музыку.

Далее используем эту команду:

```
import os
os.system("TASKKILL /F /IM <имя процесса>.exe")
```

В моем случае это:

```
os.system("TASKKILL /F /IM Music.UI.exe")
```

Программа закрывается.